# how can i get microsoft publisher 97 to work on new Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7

My parents use MS Publisher 97 and it will not work with their new computer running Windows 7.  Error message:  Publisher can not start the page wizard design assistant.  Running the compatibility for previous windows versions does not fix the problem.  Really do not want to upgrade Publisher as they are not very computer savvy and a new program would most likely be a huge learning curve.  Any help out there?

Answer (score 1):

If they have the right version of Win7 you could try the "Virtual XP" option.  See -> http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

If you don't have that version of Win7 you can try VirtualBox or VMWare.  MS Pub 97 will probably work with VirtualBox on Win7 running an XP or Windows 2000 virtual machine.  The guest OS list includes Windows 98 http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes but with reduced function (slow).  But slow on a new box might be faster than they're used to on the older box for all I know.

It's not trivial to set up VirtulBox but it's not hard either.  Took me about half an hour to read documentation and install, with most of the time spent reading...  It's free software but supported by a big company (Oracle) so it DOES work for most people.  I assume VMware has similar capability but have not installed/used it myself.  You WILL need a valid licensed copy of Windows to install on the virtual machine, but I assume you have that from the older machine.

PS: I also have some old *.PUB files and I'm going to use this method myself eventually - unless someone else answers with a "converter" program.